# Use an image named after the branch in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

As part of my bitbucket pipeline I build and push an image to AWS ECR named after the feature branch, eg: `<ecr_uri>/<my_bucket>:<feature_branch>`. I want to use that image as my base image in a future step, but bitbucket says that my image name is name is invalid.

```
- step:
    image:
        name: <ecr_uri>/<my_bucket>:$BITBUCKET_BRANCH
        aws:
            access-key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
            secret-key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Is there a way to use an image named after the feature branch?

Comment: you can find detailed system variables here https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I don't think you can use a system variable in the image name in a pipeline step.

Comment: Hmm, it might be that the feature branch has a weird string buildup that breaks the tag i.e funny characters. Have you tried using BITBUCKET_COMMIT after the image name instead. I would recommend export in your pipeline the image name including the tag as the BITBUCKET_COMMIT. You will be able to use that exported name in other steps as well. All depending of course what your end goal is for using the branch name as a requirement